# awsでlambda関数からrdsに接続できない

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

aws-lambdaでlinebotを作成したいと思っています。
その中でaws-rdsで作成したデータベースにPyMySQLで接続しようとこちらのコードを書いたところ、エラーになってしまいました。

```
def pickupDatabase():
    rds_host  = "rdsのエンドポイント"
    name = rds_config.db_username
    password = rds_config.db_password
    db_name = rds_config.db_name
    
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
    msg = ""
    item_count = 0
    
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("select * from content")
        for row in cur:
            item_count += 1
            #logger.info(row)
    conn.close()
    
    return "Added %d items from RDS MySQL table" %(item_count)
```

**試してみたこと**
1.ロールの確認
(参考サイト：https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html)
→参考サイトの実行ロールを作成するというところを参考に作ったのですが変わりませんでした。

2.rds_configの中身を取り出せているかを確認
→取り出せていました。間違えてないことも確認済みです。

**表示されたエラーメッセージ**

> [ERROR] OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'test-database.cpstxnucpjex.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)")

エラーの原因はデータベースに接続できなかったことだと思うのですが、調べてVPN設定などもしてみたのですがうまくいきません。
初心者質問で恐縮ですが、この場合の確認事項、よくある修正方法など教えてほしいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 【セキュリティグループ設定(インバウンド、アウトバウンド共通)】
タイプ→すべてのトラフィック
ソース→マイIP。

RDS、Lambdaのセキュリティグループはインバウンド、アウトバウンドともに上記のセキュリティグループが設定されています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決したのでさらに追記で回答します。
Lambdaで接続しているセキュリティグループのアウトバウンドルールとインバウンドルールにVPCのサブネットのCIDRを追加したらうまく動くようになりました。

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-rds-connection-timeouts/
上記URLのセキュリティグループのルールを確認するというところを見逃してしまっていたようです。
失礼いたしました。

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージからすると、認証の前にネットワークレベルで接続できていないのではないかと思われます。

RDS は VPC 内に配置されるサービスで、Lambda はデフォルトでは VPC 外に配置されるサービスです。ですのでネットワークが接続できるには二つの方法があります。

- Lambda に VPC を割り当てる
- RDS を Public access 可能にする

後者は一般的におすすめではないため、前者がおすすめです。Lambda に VPC を割り当てる方法は以下に書かれています。

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

注意としては、Lambda からインターネットにアクセスできる必要がある場合です。VPC を割り当てると、Lambda からインターネットへのアクセスも VPC 経由となり、NAT Gateway が必要になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一応VPCに関してはサイトを見ながら下記手順でやってみました。
1.IAMの実行ロールを作成
2.作成した実行ロールをlambdaで読み込み

張っていただいたリンク先を何度か読み返してやってみたのですがそれでも同じエラーが出てしまいます。
【aws lambda rds】などで調べなおし、ほかのサイトも確認したのですが自身の目で確認したところ特に抜けてしまっている手順が見当たりませんでした。

Comment: 例えば、LambdaをVPCに割り当てる際にセキュリティグループを割り当てると思うのですが、そのセキュリティグループからRDSにアクセスできるようにRDS側のセキュリティグループは設定できているでしょうか？

Comment: RDSのほうのパブリックアクセスは可能になっていました。また、lambdaとRDSのサブネットグループやVPC、セキュリティグループも確認してみましたが同じところにちゃんと接続していました。

Answer (score 0):

正しいのかはわかりませんがセキュリティグループのIPアドレスを0.0.0.0/0にしたら無事つながるようになりました。
参考URL:https://creepfablic.site/2021/06/07/aws-rds-mysql-client-python/#index_id1

Comment: セキュリティグループが原因であることは明確になったということですね。

パブリックアクセス可能になっていて、セキュリティグループが 0.0.0.0/0 が登録されていると、セキュリティ上あまりよくありません。Lambda替わり当たるセキュリティグループからのみ許可するように見直された方がいいと思います。
(個人的に一時的に試すだけで、データも無いとかで、許容できるという場合はいいと思いますが・・。)

Comment: やはり危ないですよね…。
試しにセキュリティグループのソースをマイIPに変更(インバウンドルール、アウトバウンドルールどちらも同じ)、RDSとLambdaどちらもインバウンドルールとアウトバウンドルールに上記セキュリティグループを設定してみたところ同じ2003エラーになってしまいました…。